# Select distinct set of values values from table in MS Sql

Tags: mysql

I have table in my db which is in MSSQL having following structure

```
DayID      Sequence           Cities       Title     Hotels   
----------------------------------------------------------------
1                 1             Manali       Day1      Hotel A      
2                 2             Manali       Day2      Hotel B     
3                 2             Delhi        Day3      Hotel C    
4                 3             Delhi        Day4      Hotel D     
5                 3             Manali       Day5      Hotel E    
6                 4             Manali       Day6      Hotel F
```

Now I need The result as following

```
Cities
------   
Manali    
Delhi   
Manali.
```

I have used group by Cities but it is giving only two cities

```
Manali
Delhi
```

But I need following output.

```
Manali    
Delhi   
Manali
```

Please Suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why is this tagged MySQL when you are talking about MSSQL?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT Cities
FROM (
   SELECT Cities, DayID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DayID) -
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cities ORDER BY DayID) AS grp
   FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY Cities, grp
ORDER BY MIN(DayID)
```

Calculated field `grp` identifies islands of consecutive records having the same `Cities` value. Using this field in a `GROUP BY` clause, we can extract the required sequence of `Cities` values.

**Note:** The above query works in SQL Server.

Comment: I think you missed comma after  DayID here:   `SELECT Cities, DayID`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos , Thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score 0):

depending on requirement you can group by
eg:
select Cities from table group by Cities

Comment: This would return Manali, Delhi.not Manali, Delhi, Manali

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the table is sorted so we can use the 'by' option in the data step:

```
 proc sort data=tablename;
 by sequence cities;
 run;
```

In the data step use the 'by' clause to select the first row of each group and output.  Only 'keep' cities as requested by user

```
 data desired;
 keep cities;
 set tablename;
 by sequence cities;
 if first.cities then output;
 run;
```

Comment: Can you add some context around your answer explaining what this does?

Comment: there you go :)